# Case sensitivity issue with Oracle Sql Developer ver - 2.1.1.64

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00936

I just started using the "Oracle Sql Developer" tool and it seems to be case sensitive when creating and calling tables.  I was always under the assumption that Oracle as database was case insensitive.  The current version of the database is 10.2.0.4.0.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 
   ( c1 VARCHAR2 (50),
     c2 VARCHAR2 (50)
   );

SELECT C1, C2 FROM t1;
-- This is fine.  No errors

SELECT c1, c2, FROM t1;
/*
Error starting at line 18 in command:
SELECT c1, c2, from t1
Error at Command Line:18 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
*/
```

I have never seen this behavior before and trying to figure out if this an issue with the tool or the database and if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definetely not an issue with the oracle database and not an issue with Oracle SQL Developer either. If this is the actual query, you have an extra comma after the second column.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE T1 ( c1 VARCHAR2 (50), c2 VARCHAR2 (50) );

Table created.

SQL> SELECT C1, C2 FROM t1;

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT c1, c2, FROM t1;
SELECT c1, c2, FROM t1
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

**SELECT c1, c2, FROM t1** should instead be just **SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1;**

In general, if you have a question where you are not sure if the tool is not working as expected, SQL Plus is your best bet to verify simple test cases. It is an invaluable tool in that sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I do have an extra comma here, and I just created this example, and I assumed that it was tool specific and was hoping that someone might know if there some option to specify within the tool.

Comment: Not quite getting your question here. Is your questions answered or do You want to know if there is some option to specify "case-insensitive" inside the tool?